# what is the step do i need to call database

Tags: java, android, database

i am new in developing android application. Now, i have a database file which is "database.accdb" in assets folder.
what should i do inside the java code in order to access the database

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ this code will help u in acessing the database which is there in assest folder..

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** I just realized that you're writing an Android application. ODBC or Microsoft Access database will NOT work in Android. SQLite is used in Android, you have to subclass `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and override `onCreate()`, and `onUpgrade()`. Below is the direction of how to access Microsoft Access database on a regular Java program.

---

Looks like you're trying to access a Microsoft Access database. In this case, you need to instantiate the JDBC-ODBC driver by

```
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
    String connectionUri = "jdbc:odbc:" + /*PATH TO YOUR FILENAME*/;
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, username, password);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can use your connection like you use any other JDBC database connection. For example, you can do:

```
Connection connection = .... /* Get my connection */;
try {
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email LIKE ?");
    ps.setString(1, email);
    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()) {
        /* do whatever you want with the result */
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    /* Close the connection */
}
```

Comment: frank, i still not understand. can i direct contact with you?
my msn/skype/facebok -> chinese_boy89@hotmail.com. please add me

Comment: Basically, you're trying to use Microsoft Access database in an Android application, right? If so, it won't work because Android doesn't support it.

Comment: yup, i am plan to do so, since you said android cannot work with it, so what should i do now?

Comment: You have to use SQLite instead. SQLite is a compact database used by both Android and iOS to store data. As @raj said, the link in his post could help you setup with SQLite.

Comment: what if i want to use the ms access database? i go search the odbc-jdbc driver, when i go to localhost there, the username and password i cannot get correctly

Comment: Android does not support ODBC, or even Java's JDBC. Remember that Android doesn't implement the whole Java SE spec. So you cannot use MS Access database. It has to be SQLite, or flat file.

Comment: oh i see, then now i use SQLiteOpenHelper. i face the problem that is 
1) i can create row data with this, initialvalues.put(TITLE, ProgramTitle);
2) but how i know whether it has success added into the table or not?
it can run but got runtime error. but i not sure where is the problem

*p/s i got "ProgramDbAdapter" class, "Program" class extends ExpandableListActivity{private ProgramDbAdapter mDbHelper;}